# Groovy joda-time convert time

Tags: grails, groovy, jodatime

In my domain I have

```
Time startTime
Time endTime
```

In my controller I need to covert the time from the view which is in a format of HH:MM to the acceptable format to submit to the domain. I have installed the plugin Joda-Time but I've come a bit stuck.

```
        def startTime = params.startTime
        def fmt_in = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss")
        def fmt_out = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()

        println fmt_out.print(fmt_in.parseDateTime(startTime))
```

sorry, newbie to groovy grails

Comment: Do you mean `LocalTime` instead of `Time`?

Answer (score 0):

After parsing for DateTime, you need to transform it to the desired type. For date and time without considering timezone I suggest you to use `LocalDateTime` and `LocalTime`.

```
def formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss")
LocalTime time = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(params.startTime).toLocalTime()
```